# How should I write a function with a numbers extension?

Tags: python, function

I am trying to create a code that has a function in it for calculating a random number between two numbers - which I choose when writing the code - and then take that away from Num1. However, when I run it, the number it generates is always 0. Please can you tell me how to write this function properly! Here is the code below.

```
import random
MinNum = int(0)
MaxNum = int(0)
Num1 = int(36)

def RandomNum(x,y,z):
    MinNum = x
    MaxNum = y
    Num1 = z
    Num1 = Num1 - random.randint(MinNum, MaxNum)

RandomNum(5,17,Num1) # - I would type it in the code like this
print(Num1) # - This should print a number that is equal to: 36 - the number generated.
```

Comment: Your function does not return anything, and produces no other side-effects, therefore there is absolutely no point in even calling it.

Comment: All your function is doing is creating some local variables. You either need to `return` something from it, or make it change some of those global variables (avoid this)

Comment: If you want to change global variables in a function you have to declare them as [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) first — otherwise by default they'll just be local variables that can only be accessed within the function.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be getting confused between local and global variables. For `RandomNum` to be able to change the value of `Num1`, you need to make the variable global, otherwise, it will create a separate `Num1` variable that only applies for the duration of the `RandomNum` function. This is called scope.

For example

```
def f():
    a = 2 # this a is local to the f() function.
    print('Inside of f (local scope), a =', a)

a = 1 # this is set in the global scope
f()
print('On the global level (global scope) a =', a) # Now that are f() function is finished, a will go back to being equal to 1
```

Outputs

> Inside of f (local scope), a = 2
>
> On the global level (global scope) a = 1

However, you can declare a variable as being global, like so.

```
def f():
    global a # this time a will refer to the same variable inside and outside of our f() function
    a = 2
    print('Inside of f (local scope), a =', a)

a = 1
f()
print('On the global level (global scope) a =', a)
```

And then you get

> Inside of f (local scope), a = 2
>
> On the global level (global scope) a = 2

If we apply this to your code, we can fix it like so.

```
import random
MinNum = int(0)
MaxNum = int(0)
Num1 = int(36)

def RandomNum(x,y,z):
    global MinNum, MaxNum, Num1
    MinNum = x
    MaxNum = y
    Num1 = z
    Num1 = Num1 - random.randint(MinNum, MaxNum)

RandomNum(5,17,Num1)
print(Num1)
```

However, it is far more common to have a function return something, instead of manipulating global variables. Your function could also be rewritten like so.

```
import random

def RandomNum(minNum, maxNum, subtractedFrom):
    return subtractedFrom - random.randint(minNum, maxNum)

num1 = RandomNum(5, 17, 36)
print(result)
```

Although there really is no reason to be have this function in the first place as  `RandomNum(5, 17, 36)` is the same thing as `random.randint(19, 31)`, so your code could simply be written as

```
import random
print( random.randint(19, 31) )
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question! It really helped. The reason why I need it to be subtracted from a variable is because that's what's going to happen in the project I'm working on.